# sftp put file in mbox with R

Tags: r

I need to use sftp and put .txt files into a MFT server. Is it possible using R?

I have seen examples on how to get a file using sftp using RCurl.

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Do you mean the mailbox file/dir format [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox)? There's no such thing as a mbox-server in that context. Perhaps you mean IMAP? POP? Exchange? Curl (and therefore `RCurl`) supports [many protocols](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), please be clearer what you are trying to do outside of that.

Comment: I am talking about a MFT server.

Comment: Frankly I've never heard of a monolithic MFT server. My cursory (3 minutes) research suggests it is built around already-existing technologies, ranging from FTP, SFTP, to HTTP(S) and other similar protocols. (I might easily be wrong here, this is a little speculation.) To answer your question *"is it possible"*, almost certainly "yes" given those assumptions, but it depends on whatever service you are actually connecting to. If you have a specific product, please include it (ideally with a link to technical specs that define an API).l

Answer (score 0):

I could do it using ftpUpload function.

```
ftpUpload(<file_to_be_uploaded>,
        "sftp://SFTPServer/Destination",
        userpwd = "login:password"
      )
```